# Efficiently find adjacent values in vector

Tags: r, vector

I have an R data frame with a vector of numbers representing positions along a chromosome and a vector of gene names. I also have a vector of start positions of interesting elements on that chromosome. I'd like to extract the names and positions of the 3 closest genes both above and below each element, and I'm wondering the most efficient way to go about this.

For example:

```
genes <- data.frame("geneStart"=sort(sample(500,10)), "geneName"=sample(LETTERS,10))
genes
   geneStart geneName
1         66        X
2        158        U
3        262        N
4        385        D
5        387        H
6        418        Z
7        464        J
8        469        Y
9        475        L
10       491        I
```

I want to end up with a function, let's call it `getAdjacent`, like so:

```
getAdjacent(280)
[1] "X" "U" "N" "D" "H" "Z"
getAdjacent(479)
[1] "J" "Y" "L" "I" NA NA
```

Comment: When you say 3 closest, do you mean the gene that contains the element, then either 3 above and 2 below, or vice versa? Do you decide based on the gene lengths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `findInterval`:

```
getAdjacent <- function(x) {
   idx       <- findInterval(x, genes$geneStart)
   range.idx <- (idx-2):(idx+3)
   range.idx <- ifelse(range.idx <= 0, NA, range.idx)
   as.character(genes$geneName)[range.idx]
}
```

You might have to adjust the behavior if `x` belongs to `genes$geneStart` depending on your preference.

Comment: +1 I was going along these lines with `findInterval`, but I was considering if the idx-2 / idx+3 should ever be switched depending on where the starting position in the gene was

Answer (score 2):

My version:

```
getAdjacent <-function(x){
ind <-which(abs(genes[,1]-x)==min(abs(genes[,1]-x))) #which row is closest
out <-genes[max(1,ind-3):min(nrow(genes),ind+2),2]   #indexed for closest match
return(as.character(out))
}
```

Comment: This answer seems better to me as 1) it finds the "closest genes" (`findInterval(99,c(1,10,100))` gives 2 while we would like 3 since 99 is closest to 100). And 2) it address the problems of the edges of the array. Minor point; would it not be more efficient/readable to pre-calculate `abs(genes[,1]-x)` rather than having the expression twice though ?

Comment: You are right. It would probably be more efficient to pre-calculate the absolute differences. I just wanted to keep my solution to three lines...